# ReactJS GoogleOAuth login authentication cannot define result and token issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth, token

I'm creating web-app with ReactJS and trying to add a Google Sign-In component with GoogleOAuth authentication. I have imported the token to .env file, but I cannot figure out why 'result' and 'token' is undefined when trying to fetch the google login credentials in auth.js:

[image]

I've noticed that Google recently changed the authentication process and these are my code that I have updated (Google API Token is stored in '.env.development' file):

Auth.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useStyles from "./styles";
import Input from "./input";
import { GoogleLogin, googleLogout } from "@react-oauth/google";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Auth = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleShowPassword = () =>
    setShowPassword((prevShowPassword) => !prevShowPassword);

  const handleSubmit = () => {};

  const handleChange = () => {};

  const switchMode = () => {
    setIsSignup((prevIsSignup) => !prevIsSignup);
    handleShowPassword(false);
  };

  const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
    const result = res?.profileObj;
    const token = res?.tokenId;

    try {
        dispatch( { type: 'AUTH', data: { result, token }});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const googleFailure = (error) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.log("Google Sign In was unsuccessful. Try Again later")
  };

  const user = false;
  
  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={3}>
          <GoogleLogin
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <Button
                className={classes.googleButton}
                color="primary"
                fullWidth
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                startIcon={<Icon />}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Google Sign In
              </Button>
            )}
            onSuccess = {googleSuccess}
            onFailure = {googleFailure}
            cookiePolicy = "single_host_origin"
          />
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

auth.js (in reducers)

```
import { AUTH, LOGOUT } from '../constants/actionTypes';

const authReducer = (state = { authData: null }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTH:

            console.log(action?.data);
            return state;

        default:

            return state;
    }
};

export default authReducer;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container, Grow, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Auth from './components/Auth/Auth';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import useStyles from './styles';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

const App = () => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [currentId, dispatch]);

  return (
      <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId = {`${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}`}>
      
      {/* <Grow in>
        <Container>
          <Grid container justify = "space-between" alignItems = "stretch" spacing = {3}>
            <Grid item xs = {12} sm = {7}>
              <Posts setCurrentId = {setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs = {12} sm = {4}>
              <Form currentId = {currentId} setCurrentId = {setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Grow> */}

      <List/>
    
      
      <Routes>
    
        <Route path = "/Auth" element = {<Auth />} />
        
      </Routes>
    <Footer>

    </Footer>


    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

actionTypes.js

```
export const CREATE = 'CREATE';
export const UPDATE = 'UPDATE';
export const DELETE = 'DELETE';
export const FETCH_ALL = 'FETCH_ALL';
export const LIKE = 'LIKE';

export const AUTH = 'AUTH';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';
```

Answer (score 1):

They are undefined because you are trying to access the JWT claims that are not there. If you `console.log(res)` then you inspect the element, you will see a list of JWT claims that google returns and then try to access what you need.

You want to make sure that `tokenId` and `profileObj` is there.

Answer (score 0):

In your Auth.js file update your googleSuccess function as follows :
Also import :
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

```
const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
      
      const result = jwt_decode(res?.credential);
    
      try {
          dispatch({type: 'AUTH', data: {result}});
          

      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  };
```